# Swift - data from an array of struct not showing on tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, struct

**How can I show data on a tableview with its origin from a struct and one extra cell for adding action?**

All data(invoice and items) is fetched from a server and it works fine.

If I add a print, it shows all data  on the console.

> [Invoice.InvoiceItem(invoice_detail_id: 13, description: oi,
>   unit_price: 2, quantity: 1), Invoice.InvoiceItem(invoice_detail_id:
>   14, description: re, unit_price: 3, quantity: 2),
>   Invoice.InvoiceItem(invoice_detail_id: 15, description: fsdf,
>   unit_price: 4, quantity: 3)]

The problem is that it doesnt populate on the tableview. I tried adding or subtracting 1 without success.

Also, there is one more cell, that is not for items, but for adding a new item, and always being the last cell or the only one when there is no item.

tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) seems to be called only once... where in fact it should be 4 (3 items plus add cell)

```
import UIKit

class InvoiceItemCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var unitPriceQuantityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lineTotalLabel: UILabel!

}

class InvoiceViewController: UIViewController, AccessoryToolbarDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var dateIssueTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var dueDateTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var taxDescriptionLabel: UILabel!

    var thePicker = UIDatePicker()
    var invoice: Invoice?
    var client: Client?
    var invoiceItems : [InvoiceItem] = [InvoiceItem]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        dateIssueTextField.delegate = self
        dueDateTextField.delegate = self

        self.thePicker = UIDatePicker(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 216))
        self.thePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.thePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date

        //data will be loaded from an API to a server. Hard Coded now just for testing
        setUpTextFieldPicker(textField: dateIssueTextField)
        setUpTextFieldPicker(textField: dueDateTextField)

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.rowHeight = 75

    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.title = "New"
        taxDescriptionLabel.text = "Tax @ 0%"

        if (invoice?.invoice_id) != nil {
            self.title = "Edit"
            dueDateTextField.text = invoice?.due_date
            dateIssueTextField.text = invoice?.date_issue
            let taxDescription = invoice?.tax.description
            taxDescriptionLabel.text = "Tax @ \(taxDescription ?? "0")%"

            let invoiceItems = invoice?.items


            print("Will Appear")
            print(invoiceItems!)
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return invoiceItems.count + 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == (invoiceItems.count)) {
            return 50
        } else {
            return 75
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        //if ((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row == (invoiceItems.count)) {
        print(indexPath.row)
        if (indexPath.row == (invoiceItems.count)) {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InvoiceAddCell", for: indexPath)
            print("add cell")
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "InvoiceItemCell", for: indexPath) as! InvoiceItemCell
            let item = invoiceItems[indexPath.row]
            print("Cell")

            cell.descriptionLabel.text = item.description

            let partial = (item.unit_price?.description)!+" X "+(item.quantity?.description)!
            cell.unitPriceQuantityLabel.text = partial

            let lineTotal = item.unit_price * item.quantity
            cell.lineTotalLabel.text = lineTotal.description
            return cell
        }



    }


    func doneClicked(for textField: UITextField) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.timeStyle = .none

        //show on text field
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        textField.text = dateFormatter.string(from: thePicker.date)

        //formated to store on mysql
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
        let finalDate: String = dateFormatter.string(from: thePicker.date)
        print(finalDate)
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func cancelClicked(for textField: UITextField) {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }

    func setUpTextFieldPicker(textField: UITextField) {
        textField.inputView = thePicker
        let toolbar = AccessoryToolbar(for: textField)
        toolbar.accessoryDelegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
        if let fullDate = dateFormatter.date(from: textField.text!) {
            thePicker.date = fullDate
        } else {
            thePicker.date = Date()
        }

        return true
    }



}
```

*Structs*

```
struct InvoiceItem: Codable {
    var invoice_detail_id: Int!
    let description: String!
    let unit_price: Decimal!
    let quantity: Decimal!

    init(invoice_detail_id: Int! = nil, description: String, unit_price: Decimal, quantity: Decimal) {
        self.invoice_detail_id = invoice_detail_id
        self.description = description
        self.unit_price = unit_price
        self.quantity = quantity
    }

}

//let invoiceItems = [InvoiceItem(invoice_detail_id: 1, description: "AB", unit_price: 10.22, quantity: 2),
//                    InvoiceItem(invoice_detail_id: 2, description: "fsdsdsdfsdf", unit_price: 44.35, quantity: 10)]

struct Invoice: Codable {
    var invoice_id: Int!
    let client_id: Int!
    let tax: Decimal!
    let date_issue: String!
    let due_date: String!
    let amount_paid: Decimal!
    let date_transaction: String!
    let voided: Int!
    let note: String!
    let invoice_number: String!
    let status: String!
    let items: [InvoiceItem]!

    init(invoice_id: Int! = nil, client_id: Int! = nil,tax: Decimal, date_issue: String, due_date: String, amount_paid: Decimal, date_transaction: String, voided: Int, note: String, invoice_number: String, status: String, items: InvoiceItem) {
        self.invoice_id = invoice_id
        self.client_id = client_id
        self.tax = tax
        self.date_issue = date_issue
        self.due_date = due_date
        self.amount_paid = amount_paid
        self.date_transaction = date_transaction
        self.voided = voided
        self.note = note
        self.invoice_number = invoice_number
        self.status = status
        self.items = [items]

    }
}
```

Comment: How does `invoice` get set to something other than nil?

Comment: From a prev view passing as a parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with `viewWillAppear`. The local `invoiceItems` there is not the `invoiceItems` property used by the table view's data source.

Change it as follows:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    self.title = "New"
    taxDescriptionLabel.text = "Tax @ 0%"

    if (invoice?.invoice_id) != nil {
        self.title = "Edit"
        dueDateTextField.text = invoice?.due_date
        dateIssueTextField.text = invoice?.date_issue
        let taxDescription = invoice?.tax.description
        taxDescriptionLabel.text = "Tax @ \(taxDescription ?? "0")%"

        invoiceItems = invoice?.items // No let

        print("Will Appear")
        print(invoiceItems!)
    }
}
```

And all of this code really should be in `viewDidLoad`, not `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: It works! I use will appear because did load is called only when the view is created... I have a prev view with a list of invoices and when touch the cell, it calls this view passing the selected invoice.